# Something wrong in json parsing in php

Tags: php, json

I'm getting the following JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "startDate": "2012-07-12 11:21:38 +0530",
        "totalTime": 0
    },
    {
        "startDate": "2012-07-11 11:27:33 +0530",
        "totalTime": 0
    },
    {
        "startDate": "2012-07-16 18:38:37 +0530",
        "totalTime": 0
    },
    {
        "startDate": "2012-07-17 14:18:32 +0530",
        "totalTime": 0
    }
]
```

i want make array of startDate and totalTime, i have used these two lines but it wont work,  please suggest..

```
    $obj  = json_decode($dateTimeArr); 
    $dateAr = $obj->{'startDate'};
```

Comment: A suggestion: How does it know which of the objects in the JSON response it should get the start date of? Try making sure that you're getting the first of the three, perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON string represents an Array or Objects. Each item of the array is an object like `{"startDate":"2012-07-12 11:21:38 +0530","totalTime":0}`.

So `json_decode($dateTimeArr);` returns the array. If you want to access to the first element you can use the `$obj[0]` syntax. Then to get the startDate property, use `$obj[0]->startDate`.

You can iterate over all array's items using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($obj as $item) {
    echo $item->startDate, "\n";
}
```